# Pythonic way to match multiple values in a list of lists to another list of lists and return a value

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to match two or more values from a list of lists to another list of lists and return a value from one of the lists. Much like SQL's on clause - on x.field = y.field and x.field = y.field.

Picture a list of transactions from your Amazon account. The ids are unique, but the names change (darn Amazon!). I want to use the last name/title, based on max date. I could probably do the below with the initial data set, but couldn't think of how. I'm reading in the rows as a list of lists.

I'm just working on a personal project combing through Amazon purchases, but could see this being very useful down the road. I have a solution, but I think it will run very long depending on the size of the data. I've seen people call out Pandas' dataframe as a solution, but I'm trying to learn Python's standard libraries first. It's my first question on Stack, I apologize and thank you in advance.

```
#Example data set comes from a csv I've read into different list of lists
#Fields in order are ID, date (max date from csv to id) -- data set is unique row count 140
X = [['b12', 8/1/2019], ['c34', 7/25/2018],..]
#Fields in order are ID, date, Name -- data set is unique, due to date, row count 1,231
Y = [['b12', 6/23/19, 'item 1'], ['b12', 7/21/19, 'item 1.0'], ['b12', 8/1/19, 'item 1.1'],..]

#Code that works, but I'm sure is 'expensive'
for i in X:
    for n in Y:
        if i[0] == n[0] and i[1] == n[1]:
           i.append(x[2])
        else: continue


#Result is either I append to X (like I have) or create a new list of lists all together
X
[['b12', 8/1/2019, 'item 1.1'], ['c34', 7/25/2019, 'item 2.8'],...]
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what the input is and what the desired output is. Can you clarify?

Comment: The input would be the two list of lists (X,Y). Desired output is matching the lists on the first two values and appending the last value of Y to list X or an entirely new list that has the values from X with Y[2]. I hope that helps. As I stated, the code I have works, but i'm certain there is a better, less expensive way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping dict from your list `Y` with `(id, date)` as key and the `name` as value. Then use a list comprehension to create a new list from list `X` with the the mapped value from the mapping dict

```
>>> X = [['b12', '8/1/2019'], ['c34', '7/25/2018']]
>>> Y = [['b12', '6/23/19', 'item 1'], ['b12', '7/21/19', 'item 1.0'], ['b12', '8/1/19', 'item 1.1'], ['c34', '7/25/18', 'item2.1']]
>>> 
>>> mapping = {(id, date):name for id,date,name in Y}
>>> res = [[id, date, mapping[(id, date.replace('/20', '/'))]] for id,date in X]
>>> 
>>> print (res)
[['b12', '8/1/2019', 'item 1.1'], ['c34', '7/25/2018', 'item2.1']]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using datetime to make the dates actual date objects. So I shouldn't need the replace. I'll have to test the times out to see if this run faster